# Why isn't the std::string's move constructor called here?

Tags: c++, move

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class S
{
public:

  S(std::string && s)
  : str(std::move(s))
  {
  }

  /* Why does a copy of s happen somewhere in here? */
  S(std::string && s, bool dummyArg)
  : str(s)
  {
  }

  void printVal() const
  {
    cout << "S::s is \"" << str << "\"\n";
  }

private:
  string str;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  string str1{"Some string that I want to move into S"};
  string str2{"Some other string that I want to move into S"};

  // S s0{str1}; // Does not compile because no constructor matches
  S s1{std::move(str1)};
  S s2{std::move(str2), false};

  s1.printVal();
  cout << "str1 is: \"" << str1 << "\"\n";

  cout << "\n";

  s2.printVal();
  cout << "str2 is : \"" << str2 << "\"\n";
}
```

Which produces the following output: (compiled with Clang (XCode 9))

```
S::s is "Some string that I want to move into S"
str1 is: ""

S::s is "Some other string that I want to move into S"
str2 is : "Some other string that I want to move into S"
```

So we can clearly see that when using the second constructor, `str2` isn't moved into `S::str`. I do not understand why adding an `std::move` makes a difference as `std::move` is just does a `static_cast<T&&>` on its arguments, which is already the type of the constructor's argument.